# the amount of dynamic allocated memory a pointer would take in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
const int SIZE = 1000;
typedef int* IntPointer;
IntPointer ip;
do {
ip = new int[ SIZE ];
cout << "Memory allocated " << endl << flush;
} while (ip != nullptr);
}
```

This code is suppose to test the amount of memory used by the ip every time it loops. 
I tried to print out the value of ip, which is the memory address in hex I believe, I can see everytime it loops once, the address will increase 4000 in dec. So, is it correct that every ip will take 4000 bytes memory? I am wondering if there is any function to get the value of memory used by every ip? If not, how do I get the size of cumulative memory use within the loop? 
Appreciate your answer. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the memory taken by a dynamically allocated *array*, not by a pointer. Your title is misleading.

Comment: Unless you use the nothrow variant of `new`, it will throw an exception, not return a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sizeof() function to get the size in bytes. Make sure to dereference the pointer however, otherwise you'll get the size of the pointer itself, not the memory it points to. Plus just a note, make sure you get around to releasing memory allocated by a pointer. Anything you put on the heap is your own problem, unlike the stack. (You may already be aware but it doesn't hurt to reiterate.)

In your code, most of the data is simply lost, as your pointer can only point at one thing at a time.

Edit: Reading this correctly now, yeah you can't just get the size of the array. Dereferencing will just give you the size of the first element. You know the count of the array however, so you can simply multiply. If your elements could be different sizes (which in your case they can't) I'm not entirely sure of what you would do.

Comment: Using `sizeof` on the dereferenced pointer only gives you the size of a single element, not the size of the whole array.

Comment: Arg, apologies didn't even read his question right, for some reason I read that as him calling new for one element many times. Shouldn't try this when I'm tired.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is one part of my lab. The purpose of this program is to know the size of heap memory taken by each array created. This program will stop when the memory is used up...I just have no idea how to get the size of each array created... I tried to print out the value of ip. It seemed to be the address of the first element in every int array created. I converted the hex address to decimal and calculated the differences between each address. It was 4004. It seemed to be one array plus one int...

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to get the ammount of memory allocated at runtime. You can get the amount of memory by tracking the size and using `sizeof(int)*SIZE` byte for the array. You can't get the memory at runtime using sizeof. sizeof is a compile time operator.

The memory allocator will also allocate a struct internally to track the memory chunk and the size of it, but this bookkeeping struct isn't usually your concern, unless you want to make your own memory allocator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have to allocate memory to know about this.

To get size of one pointer use below,

```
cout << "Memory allocated for one IntPointer :"<<sizeof(IntPointer);
```

To get size of 1000 Int* objects use as below,

```
cout << "Memory allocated for "<< SIZE <<" IntPointers :"<<sizeof(IntPointer*SIZE );
```

you are getting 4000 as you allocate memory for 1000 int* i.e 4*1000 = 4000.

Answer (score 0):

A integer is on your system 4 bytes. So having a int array of 1000 -> 4000 bytes. That's correct. The `std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl;` function will show you that your integer has a size of 4 bytes.